# To implement multidimensional gaussian kernel

Tags: r, algorithm

How to create a function that calculate multidimensional gaussian kernel for variables below?

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(30), ncol = 3)
```

Comment: Look at the `ks` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ks/index.html

Comment: I know this package, but I need to calculate, manually.